# Dialoge action not working

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have created dialog and i wanted to call a function when user press ok button from dialoge. But it seems that function is not calling on clicking the ok button. Here is my code

```
local alert = native.showAlert( "TapNTrack", "You Lost",  "OK", onComplete )

local function onComplete(event)
    print("oncomplete");
    if "clicked" == event.action then --1
      local i = event.index --2
      if i == 1 then
       gotoLevels()
       end --2
     end-- 1
 end
```

Comment: Define the function _before_ creating the `alert` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
local function onComplete( event )
  if "clicked" == event.action then
    local i = event.index
    if 1 == i then
      print("OK")
    elseif 2 == i then
      print("Cancel")
    end
  end
end

local alert = native.showAlert( "Title", "Message", { "OK", "Cancel" }, onComplete )
```

Keep Coding................ :)